# Pattern Matching for instanceof - compile-time error for a [type] instanceof [subtype]

Tags: java, instanceof, jep

Reading this JDK Enhancement Proposal for Pattern Matching for instanceof:

https://openjdk.org/jeps/394

> Make it a compile-time error for a pattern instanceof expression to
> compare an expression of type S against a pattern of type T, where S
> is a subtype of T. (This instanceof expression will always succeed and
> is then pointless. The opposite case, where a pattern match will
> always fail, is already a compile-time error.)

Then as Integer is a subtype of Number, I would expect a compile-time error for this code, but it works:

```
Integer n = 1;
if (n instanceof Number) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

I would expect the compile-time error because as the JEP pointed this code is pointless, alsways succeed.

Comment: "S against a pattern of type T, where S is a subtype of T", `Number` is not a subtype of `Integer`.

Comment: I got confuse by "pattern instanceof expression". I think this text in JEP is wrong, it should be '"expression instanceof pattern", right?

Comment: I have just updated code in my question, the new code still compiles. It should not compile as it is pointless, but it runs.

Comment: Which java version are you using? This JEP was delivered in JDK 14 as preview feature. And finalized in JDK 16.

Comment: Java 17 version

Comment: Why should it not compile? There is no pattern matching involved; that is just the old `instanceof`, also called [*type comparison operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)

Comment: Try writing `n instanceof Number num`

Comment: ok, I see what happens: if (n instanceof Number) compiles, but if (n instanceof Number x) does not compile.

Comment: it does not compile cos the JEP pointed out: "This instanceof expression will always succeed and is then pointless."

Comment: sorry, i was missing the pattern local variable, but the fact the it does not compile for pattern-matching instanceof but it compiles for type instanceof. That behavior looks confusing. Prob it should stay like this due to support old code.

Comment: please also be aware that JEP means "JDK Enhancement **Proposal**" - the JLS (Java Language Specification) should be the last word - and it does not mention an error for that code (well, at least I did not find it)

Comment: how can I know this JEP is included in JLS 17? JEP 394 was included in JDK 16 release. As it is listed in https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16all-relnotes.html . Can I deduce every JEP in JDK 16 is included in JDK 17?

Comment: from the header: "*Status Closed / Delivered*" and "*Release 16*" - well, if release notes of 17 does not mention it being removed or changed, it must be there (but just my opinion/my logic)

Comment: @user85421 in Java 17 throw an error "expression type Integer is a subtype of pattern type Number", check here https://editor.javadevjournal.com/java-17-compiler.html

Comment: I see, according JLS: "**If the type of the RelationalExpression is a subtype of the type of the Pattern, then a compile-time error occurs**", that was removed in Java 21

Comment: I could imagine it was  changed as part of JEP 440 (Record Patterns) [or even JEP441 (PM for switch)] - kind of because a record is s subtype of itself, but that must be allowed for Pattern Matching with records to work

Comment: @user85421 I wouldn’t say “must be allowed” but it would reduce the usefulness of pattern matching if decomposing required the expression to have a strict supertype of the record type. We would end up inserting pointless widening type casts, just to be able to decompose a record.